# linter-csslint:: Error while running CSSLint

Tags: html, css, atom-editor, linter

I am newbie in web development. I have installed atom and was working on project using HTML and CSS. Atom was working absolutely fine with HTML code however when i tried to integrate external css file with HTML then it gives the following error. Can anybody please help. the error is as follows:

linter-csslint:: Error while running CSSLint!
'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You don't have node installed or available in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org) seems some others that use Atom with CSSLint also had this issue: [AtomLinter/linter-csslint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-csslint/issues/172)

I'm not sure how important CSSLint is to this project but if you don't need it try and removing it from your package list before you try downloading anything (if its a bare bones project)